# DayRoman typeface not working properly

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I'm using pdfLaTeX with DayRoman S font package. I've installed the package through the [getnonfreefonts](http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) script, then loaded it using the following command in the preamble of my document:

```
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{dayroms}
```

as explained in the dedicated section at the [LaTeX font catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/dayromans/).

Unfortunately, the *s* character is not displaying properly, as I get elongated s's when the character is final as well.
[image: Should be "uſitatas", and so on]

As you can see from the picture, the central and final s's do not differ, as they should (*uſitatas* instead of *uſitaſ*, see also [here](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/dayromans/dayromans-2.png) ). 
Every other ligature is correctly working. I would be thankful if someone could help working this out.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It seems to be a problem with `fonstpec` not making the correct font feature available. Maybe you could check which exactly are available for this font with the lcdf type tools

Comment: @Bernard the questions starts with `I'm using pdfLaTeX`, so fontspec is not relevant.

Comment: I don't have this font installed, so I can't test it, but I would be surprised if pdflatex could automatically determine the position of an s (especially such an old package). The documentation (dayroman.txt in a zip file) says on the topic of long/round s: “When using the font family "dayroms", entering the `s` yields the so-called long s. The round s (aka "final s") can be created by entering `s:`.  This method was introduced with Y. Haralambous' old-german fonts and has been established as a quasi-standard with TeX.  The drawback is, that `\MakeUppercase` does not handle `s:` properly.”

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Does pdflatex have any way to manage  long s correctly (or even historic ligatures)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enter the round s with `s:`. (see the documentation that you can access with `texdoc dayroman`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{dayroms}

\begin{document}
us:itatas
\end{document}
```

[image]